# How to find a unique number using std::find

Tags: c++, c++builder

Hey here is a trick question asked in class today, I was wondering if there is a way to find a unique number in a array, The usual method is to use two for loops and get the unique number which does not match with all the others I am using std::vectors for my array in C++ and was wondering if find could spot the unique number as I wouldn't know where the unique number is in the array.

Comment: An odd number not as in e.g. `1` or `5`, but like an unique number in a collection?

Comment: No any number eg: 25 is different and rest of the array has 30

Comment: So whats the trick question? Loop through the array, and see if the number%2==0 ?

Comment: "Odd number" means the numbers 1,3,5,7,... If you mean something else, edit your question because this is confusing. Provide an example to make it clearer.

Comment: The algorithm is quite simple and has been asked before. Basically you get the first two elements if they are the same then they are the common element and you need to find an element that differs from this one. If they differ, you pick the one that differs from the third element.

Comment: is it possible to do that with std::find?

Comment: @super - yes, but you first need to look at the first 2 or 3 elements to see which elements is the common one.

Comment: And you need to use `std::find_if`, rather than `std::find`.

Comment: @Trenin You don't need to look first.  You can look afterwards, if the results of `std::find_if` point to the second element.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we know that the vector has at least three
elements (because otherwise, the question doesn't make sense),
just look for an element different from the first.  If it
happens to be the second, of course, we have to check the third
to see whether it was the first or the second which is unique,
which means a little extra code, but roughly:

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator
findUniqueEntry( std::vector<int>::const_iterator begin,
                 std::vector<int>::const_iterator end )
{
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator result
        = std::find_if(
            next( begin ), end, []( int value) { return value != *begin );
    if ( result == next( begin ) && *result == *next( result ) ) {
        -- result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

(Not tested, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, sorting is one option.  Then your unique value(s) will have a different value on either side.

Here's another option that solves it, using std::find, in O(n^2) time(one iteration of the vector, but each iteration iterates through the whole vector, minus one element.) - sorting not required.

```
vector<int> findUniques(vector<int> values)
{
    vector<int> uniqueValues;

    vector<int>::iterator begin = values.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator end = values.end();
    vector<int>::iterator current;

    for(current = begin ; current != end ; current++)
    {
        int val = *current;
        bool foundBefore = false;
        bool foundAfter = false;
        if (std::find(begin, current, val) != current)
        {
            foundBefore = true;
        }
        else if (std::find(current + 1, end, val) != end)
        {
            foundAfter = true;
        }

        if(!foundBefore && !foundAfter)
            uniqueValues.push_back(val);
    }
    return uniqueValues;
}
```

Basically what is happening here, is that I am running ::find on the elements in the vector before my current element, and also running ::find on the elements after my current element.  Since my current element already has the value stored in 'val'(ie, it's in the vector once already), if I find it before or after the current value, then it is not a unique value.

This should find all values in the vector that are not unique, regardless of how many unique values there are.

Here's some test code to run it and see:

```
void printUniques(vector<int> uniques)
{
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    for(it = uniques.begin() ; it < uniques.end() ; it++)
    {
            cout << "Unique value: " << *it << endl;
    }
}

void WaitForKey()
{
    system("pause");
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> values;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
            values.push_back(i);
    }
    /*for(int i = 2 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
            values.push_back(i);
    }*/
    printUniques(findUniques(values));
    WaitForKey();
    return -13;
}
```

**As an added bonus:**

Here's a version that uses a map, does not use std::find, and gets the job done in O(nlogn) time - n for the for loop, and log(n) for map::find(), which uses a red-black tree.

```
map<int,bool> mapValues(vector<int> values)
{
    map<int, bool> uniques;
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < values.size() ; i++)
    {
        uniques[values[i]] = (uniques.find(values[i]) == uniques.end());
    }
    return uniques;
}

void printUniques(map<int, bool> uniques)
{
    cout << endl;
    map<int, bool>::iterator it;
    for(it = uniques.begin() ; it != uniques.end() ; it++)
    {
        if(it->second)
            cout << "Unique value: " << it->first << endl;
    }
}
```

And an explanation.  Iterate over all elements in the `vector<int>`.  If the current member is not in the map, set its value to `true`.  If it *is* in the map, set the value to `false`.  Afterwards, all values that have the value `true` are unique, and all values with `false` have one or more duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are given an array `size>=3` which contains one instance of value `A`, and all other values are `B`, then you can do this with a single for loop.

```
int find_odd(int* array, int length) {
  // In the first three elements, we are guaranteed to have 2 common ones.
  int common=array[0];
  if (array[1]!=common && array[2]!=common) 
    // The second and third elements are the common one, and the one we thought was not.
    return common;

  // Now search for the oddball.
  for (int i=0; i<length; i++) 
    if (array[i]!=common) return array[i];
}
```

**EDIT:**

> K what if more than 2 in an array of 5 are different? – super

Ah... that is a different problem.  So you have an array of size `n`, which contains the common element `c` more than once, and all other elements exactly once.  The goal is to find the set of non-common (i.e. unique) elements right?

Then you need to look at Sylvain's answer above.  I think he was answering a different question, but it would work for this.  At the end, you will have a hash map full of the counts of each value.  Loop through the hash map, and every time you see a value of 1, you will know the key is a unique value in the input array.

Comment: K what if more than 2 in an array of 5 are different?

Comment: @super Modified answer with additional info.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses a map to count number occurences. Unique number will be seen only one time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::map<int,int> mymap;
  std::map<int,int>::iterator mit;

  std::vector<int> v;
  std::vector<int> myunique;

  v.push_back(10);  v.push_back(10);
  v.push_back(20);  v.push_back(30);
  v.push_back(40);  v.push_back(30);

  std::vector<int>::iterator vit;

  // count occurence of all numbers
  for(vit=v.begin();vit!=v.end();++vit)
  {
      int number = *vit;
      mit = mymap.find(number);
      if( mit == mymap.end() )
      {
          // there's no record in map for your number yet
          mymap[number]=1; // we have seen it for the first time
      } else {
          mit->second++; // thiw one will not be unique
      }
  }

  // find the unique ones
  for(mit=mymap.begin();mit!=mymap.end();++mit)
  {
      if( mit->second == 1 ) // this was seen only one time
      {
          myunique.push_back(mit->first);
      }
  }

  // print out unique numbers
  for(vit=myunique.begin();vit!=myunique.end();++vit)
      std::cout << *vit << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Unique numbers in this example are 20 and 40. There's no need for the list to be ordered for this algorithm.

Comment: Unique number, not odd!

Comment: Oh. So i should find some example of set or map.

Comment: K i dint knw about set or maps in c++

Comment: @super: "Unique number, not odd!" And your title says "odd", so which is it? Please use more well-defined wording.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than two values (one of which has to be unique), you can do it in O(n) in time and space by iterating a first time through the array and filling a map that has as a key the value, and value the number of occurences of the key.

Then you just have to iterate through the map in order to find a value of 1. That would be a unique number.

Comment: I think you are solving a slightly different problem where the array is filled with values, one of which is unique.  For example, your array could have {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5}, and the unique answer would be 5 (the others all occurring more than once).  However, this may be the problem OP wanted to solve...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to find a number in a vector which appears only once? The nested loop if the easy solution. I don't think `std::find` or `std::find_if` is very useful here. Another option is to sort the vector so that you only need to find two consecutive numbers that are different. It seems overkill, but it is actually O(nlogn) instead of O(n^2) as the nested loop:

```
void findUnique(const std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<int> &unique)
{
  if(v.size() <= 1) 
  {
    unique = v;
    return;
  }

  unique.clear();

  vector<int> w = v;
  std::sort(w.begin(), w.end()); 

  if(w[0] != w[1]) unique.push_back(w[0]);
  for(size_t i = 1; i < w.size(); ++i)
    if(w[i-1] != w[i]) unique.push_back(w[i]);

  // unique contains the numbers that are not repeated
}
```

Comment: What if 2 numbers in the array is different? and rest are common numbers? how would u find the 2 places in the array that contain the different number then?